# Kohana 3.3 request and response

Tags: request, response, kohana

One tutorial thought me, that I can fill my template with content, by putting:

```
$this->template->body = $this->response->body();
```

But, I cant see where the response is being populated. Even dumping the request and response, its just empty.

And secondly, how can I make advantage of the already built in `Request` class, to get some output from a function, without actually redirecting to that method ? Lets say:

```
$content = Request::factory('news/latest')->execute();
```

kind regards.

Answer (score 0):

Using `$this->template->body` assumes that you are using `Controller_Template` controller. `$this->template` is a variable within `Controller_Template` representing View file `application/views/template.php`.

Setting something to `$this->template->body` passes `$body` variable to template view file. You can than use it (like `echo $body;`) within template view.

To get output from `$content = Request::factory('news/latest')->execute();` your controller which handles `news/latest` Route must produce some output. 
Than you can get this output like:

```
$response = Request::factory('news/latest')->execute();
$content = $response->body();
```